# Python linter with variables in conditional code block

Tags: python, static-analysis

Consider the following code:

```
testvar: bool = True
if testvar:
    foo: str = ''

# Statements that do not affect value of testvar

if testvar:
    bar: str = foo
```

Any linter I've tried will complain that `foo` is possibly unbound, although it obviously must be bound. Is this by design or omission, or am I wrong and it somehow could be unbound?

Also, what is the recommended way to avoid the warning?

Comment: I do not feel confident enough to answer the question, but I have always thought it to be by omission or even impossibility: Because everything is mutable, in the case that testvar changes, it could not be assigned. (which you and I assert it cannot, but I am not sure python can always guarante , given that `locals()` and such is a thing.) This is the exact reason why I usually prefer `foo = '' if testvar else None` syntax for any conditional assignment.

Comment: @Egeau Manipulating locals() and such could break any code flow, so  I don't think analysis tools take it into account. The more I think about it, the most likely explanation is that this check is too difficult to implement. The code seems perfectly valid.

Answer (score 0):

I think the linter is detecting `foo` as possibly unbound because `testvar` is mutable, therefore, it could also be changed to `False`, in such case `foo` would not have a known value (for the interpreter) and you are using it anyways. The solution is simple though, just move the definition of `foo` outside the `if` statement (in case you have more code inside, otherwise just remove the `if testvar:` line), e.g.:

```
testvar: bool = True
foo: str = ''
if testvar:
    # you can also change the value of 'foo' here
    # other statements here (if needed)...

# Statements that do not affect value of testvar

if testvar:
    bar: str = foo
```

You may also create `foo` in the same scope where it is used (as you are using `testvar` for both checks):

```
if testvar:
    foo: str = ''
    bar: str = foo
```

Comment: You don't demonstrate how testvar can be changed. It can't. I am just wondering why the linter does not check for this scenario.

Comment: @NikšaBaldun I don't know the exact reason, in fact, I agree with you, maybe this check is too difficult to implement, however, this is the proper way to solve it. Hopefully, it can help other people too.

Comment: To me, it seems cleaner and easier to just suppress the warning with `type: ignore`. If I can be certain that the variable is not unbound, and I see no cause to doubt it. I don't want to create the variable when it is not needed.